# Process specific ulimit still low after changes to soft and hard ulimits

Tags: debian, ulimit

I'm having trouble with increasing the open-files ulimit (`ulimit -n`) for a particular process on a Debian 6 server.

AFAIK I've done everything to change the servers hard and soft limits in this case, (`ulimit -n` shows 200000), but when I check the `/proc/<process_id>/limits` file it's still showing the old limits:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

---

*The steps that I have already taken to permanently increase the ulimits are:*

**Added to /etc/profile:**

```
# set ulimit n permanetly
ulimit -n 200000
```

**Added to /etc/security/limits.conf:**

```
*       soft    nofile  200000
*       hard    nofile  200000
```

**Uncommented this lime in /etc/pam.d/su**

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

**What am I missing?** Thank you!

---

Other (relevant?) info:

- The process is started in a `init.d` script with `start-stop-daemon`
- The `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory is empty

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068793/how-to-get-etc-security-limits-conf-changes-reflected-for-processes-running-und help? The /etc/pam.d/su file is looked at by `su`, so if nothing runs `su` on the way to invoking the process you're interested in, it likely won't be looked at. But the script in `/etc/init.d` is going to run as root, so you can run `ulimit` there and raise it to anything.

Comment: Did you log out and back in (or log in again with `su` or over SSH)? Settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are applied when you log in, to all processes that you'll execute in that session.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/642082/68972 : `start-stop-daemon` doesn't use PAM, but does simple `chuid` if requested, so `pam_limits` and `limits.conf` doesn't apply for the started daemon.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, the application which I was running was begun with sudo.  I believed that the limits would therefore be applied from the root user's account.  I was wrong.  Instead, I found that, although the application was running as root, the limits applied to it were the limits belonging to the user which launched the application.